# Django multi-select widget. Add arbitrary select components

Tags: django, widget, multi-select

i would like to make a widget that lets the user select a value from a drop-down list and then add new drop-down lists with values filtered based on the previous selections. I don't know where to start from....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the amount of drop-downs is finite and determinable by the time you develop the software (e.g. selecting country->city->street) I would suggest to:

1. add all the extra dropdowns (without data yet) to your form, make sure they are [hidden](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_hidden.asp)
2. use [jqueryui](https://jqueryui.com/) to un-hide and populate the dropdowns as needed using [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Don't forget to disable/hide the whole form by default and only show it if JS is enabled in browser.

Also, you will of course need another view, with which only ajax speaks.

[Here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) for you to catch the idea how the stuff should work. Sorry don't know if they have anything more similar. But: user selects something -> jquery requests data for the next dropdown -> jquery displays next populated dropdown.